If $(f_i(x))_{i\in I}$ upper limit for all $x \in M$, then $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ converges punctually
Let $(M, d)$ be a metric space and let $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of $f_i\colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ functions Lipschitz.
Question. If $(f_i(x))_{i\in I}$ upper limit for all $x \in M$, then $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ converges punctually.
I know that by hypothesis, $\{f_i(x): i \in I\}$ is upper bounded for all $x\in M$. This means there is a real number $_x$ such that $f_i(x)\leq M_x$ for everyone $i\in I$
Implication of the hypothesis: How does the set $\{f_i(x): i \in I\}$ is non-empty (since
is defined for each $i\in I$ and is limited superiorly, the supreme $\sup_{i\in I} f_i(x)$ exists and is finite for all $x\in M$. This is guaranteed by the axiom of completeness of
$\mathbb{R}$, which states that every nonempty, superiorly bounded subset of
$\mathbb{R}$ has a supremum (a minimum upper limit).
I don't know how to continue the argument.
I need to prove that: $(f_\lambda)_{\lambda \in I}$ converge punctually for $f$ if, $\forall$ $x \in X$,
$$
\lim_{\lambda \in I} f_\lambda(x) = f(x).
$$
Could anyone help?

Please write in English. What does "converge punctually" mean? What does "converge pontualmente para f se, para todo x∈X, temos" mean?

This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

@psl2Z I edited the question, it would be similar to punctual sequence convergence.

What do you mean by "$(f_i(x))_{i\in I}$ upper limit"?

@AnneBauval A family of functions $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ is said to be uniformly bounded above or upper bounded if for every $x$ in the domain, there exists a real number $M_x$ such that:
$$f_i(x) \leq M_x, \quad \forall i \in I.$$
This means that for each $x$, all values $f_i(x)$ lie below a superior bound $M_x$.

A counterexample would be $I = \mathbb{N}$ and $f_n = (-1)^n$ (constant functions are Lipschitz after all). Are you sure you didn't forget some other condition on your functions, like maybe that you want only a converging subsequence instead of the whole sequence? If it is a personal question and nothing was forgotten, I'm sorry for having written an answer in the comments.

I am used to the various notions of boundedness, but you didn't answer my question. So, again: what do you mean by "If $(f_i(x))_{i\in I}$ upper limit"?

I mentioned above what it means for $(f_i)_{i∈I}$ to be upper bounded.

@AnneBauval
Definition
The family $(f_i(x))_{i \in I}$ is upper bounded if:
$$f_i(x) \leq M_x, \quad \forall i \in I, \forall x \in D$$
where:
$D$ is the domain of the functions, $M_x$ is the upper bound for each $x$, $I$ is the index set of the functions.

Please, for the 3rd time, instead of repeating the (well-known) definition of upper bounded, edit your post to tell us your (personal) definition of "$(f_i)_{i∈I}$ upper limit" (and add a verb in this hypothesis).

@AnneBauval I really just think they were trying to tell you that this was what they meant by "upper limit", because it seems like in Spanish "límite superior" can sometimes mean upper bound instead of $\limsup$...
